# Programming STM32F3 with Atollic TrueStudio: arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy says No such file

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, programming

I am using the newly-made-free Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM 32 and built a CMSIS-based STM32F3 project from scratch.

When I try to build the project, I get the following Build Console error:

```
arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy: 'ProjectName': No such file
```

and

```
arm-atollic-eabi-size: 'ProjectName': No such file
```

I'm not even sure if the project built itself correctly, although the CDT Build Console seems to suggest that it was built. For instance, if I try to create a new Debug configuration, there is no .elf file. For reference, here is the entire console output:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.0\ide\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.0\Tools\arm-atollic-reports.jar convert hex sizeinfo list ProjectName 
Generate build reports...
Converting build output to hex
arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy: 'ProjectName': No such file
Output sent to: ProjectName.hex
Converting build output to hex done
Print size information
arm-atollic-eabi-size: 'ProjectName': No such file
Print size information done
Generate listing file
Output sent to: ProjectName.list
Generate listing file done
Generate build reports done

10:47:58 Build Finished (took 353ms)
```

Answer (score 3):

This error happens if build artifact is not selected.

Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact

[image: Build Artifact 1]

> arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy: 'ProjectName': No such file

Need to set artifact type to `Executable`, error is changed:

> Info: Nothing to build for ProjectName

It happens, because artifact extension is also required. Need to set `elf` there.

[image: Build Artifact 2]